# Cannot addEventListener to this input button

Tags: javascript

I have already used addEventListener for other context but in this context, I failed to see why it doesn't not seem to work :

UPDATE : have fixed [0] missing

https://jsfiddle.net/gyy37w7z/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>


<form action="demo_form.asp">
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" class="myClass"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</td>  
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

script :

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
function hello() {alert('hello')};
button.addEventListener("click",hello);
```

Comment: You tie event listener to input with class `myClass` instead of button

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns list of all DOM elements having the specified class. To get the first element you can use `getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0]` or you can use `querySelector('.myClass')`

Comment: @tushar have fixed still does not work

Comment: You're sure you don't just want to hook into the forms submit event, rather than clicking a text input ?

Comment: @user310291, what doesn't "work"? What do you want it to do? When you click on the input it alerts "hello", Do you want it on the submit button instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
```

returns an array of elements, you want to reach the 1st element add [0].

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
```

And you probably mixed the input with the button as well, use:

```js
// get the button by id (I added it)
button = document.getElementById("submit");

function hello() {alert('hello')};
button.addEventListener("click",hello);
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" class="myClass"><br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</td>  
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
function hello() {alert('hello')};
button.addEventListener("click",hello);
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array so if there's only one then you need index `[0]` which is the first instance

[Here is a fiddle to show working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ofoc3qex/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `class="myClass"` to button and remove same from text input.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">Username: 
      <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
      <input class="myClass" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```